# text that appears while hovering, dissapears after transition is complete

Tags: html, css, hover

I am making a website with images, while hovering the image, text appears slowly in the image

but after the transition is complete, the text disappears and hides behind the image like in the snippet below (**snippet caused HTML to derp**):

```css
.keukens, .badkamers, .toiletten{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:300px;
    padding:0;
}
.keukens:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.badkamers:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.toiletten:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.container > .links > .keukens:hover .keukensText{
    opacity:1;
}

.container > .links > .badkamers:hover .badkamersText{
    opacity:1;
}

.container > .links > .toiletten:hover .toilettenText{
    opacity:1;
}

.keukensText, .badkamersText, .toilettenText{
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.keukensText h2 span {
    color: black;
    font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

.badkamersText  h2 span {
    color: black;
    font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

.toilettenText h2 span {
    color: black;
    font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}
```

```html
<!--container-->
 <div id="container" class="container">
  <div class="links">
   <div class="col-sm-4 keukens">
    <div class="keukensText">
     <a href="keukens.html">
      <h2>
       <span>Keukens</span>
      </h2>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
      <br>
   <div class="col-sm-4 badkamers">
    <div class="badkamersText">
     <a href="badkamers.html">
      <h2>
       <span>Badkamers</span>
      </h2>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
      <br>
   <div class="col-sm-4 toiletten">
    <div class="toilettenText">
     <a href="toiletten.html">
      <h2>
       <span>Toiletten</span>
      </h2>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Can anybody help me with this? I've been stuck on this for quite a while and googled this question in so many ways but I couldn't find any answers. And now I am afraid it's going to be such a simple solution that I look like an idiot

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you need to relatively position these 3 elements `.keukensText, .badkamersText, .toilettenText` and it should work

Comment: You have 3x as much CSS as required.

Comment: @hungerstar yeah I know. I should add them all together :P

Comment: @Curt it is as i feared. the answer was so simple that I now look like an idiot. thanks! :) post it as answer and I'll vote it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to relatively position these 3 elements `.keukensText, .badkamersText, .toilettenText` and it should work

Comment: I'm just repeating the same question I asked @JPeG, but I'm desperate to know why it works. Why does relative positioning solve the problem?

Comment: Giving an element position: absolute (like you do on the psuedo :before) removes it from the normal DOM flow and puts it on top of other elements.

Adding position: relative; to your child brings the natural stacking order back

Comment: the reason it shows for a bit then hides is based on how animations work, during the animation the text is painted on its own layer (which is why you see it fade it) and then returned to it's natural order once the animation is complete (which is why it disappears).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index - this explains it pretty well

Comment: Thanks for that, but I was talking about digging deeper into how _animations_ work. I knew about the stacking order created by positioning contexts. I also thought `opacity` introduced a stacking context too as explained [here](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/). So, I thought the text should be on top even if it doesn't have `position`:`absolute` or `relative`. Guess I'm missing something. I'll have to go through that philip walton post more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. You needed to have the Text classes set to "position: absolute"

```css
.keukens, .badkamers, .toiletten{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:300px;
    padding:0;
}
.keukens a {
z-index: 40; 
}
.keukens:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.badkamers:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.toiletten:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.keukens:hover .keukensText{
    opacity:1;
    z-index: 4; 
}

.badkamers:hover .badkamersText{
    opacity:1;
}

.toiletten:hover .toilettenText{
    opacity:1;
}

.keukensText, .badkamersText, .toilettenText{
    opacity:0;
    transition: all .5s;
    position: absolute; 
}

.keukensText h2 span {
    color: black;
z-index: 50; 
font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

.badkamersText  h2 span {
    color: black;
    font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

.toilettenText h2 span {
    color: black;
    font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}
```

```html
<!--container-->
 <div id="container" class="container">
  <div class="links">
   <div class="col-sm-4 keukens">
    <div class="keukensText">
     <a href="keukens.html">
      <h2>
       <span>Keukens</span>
      </h2>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
      <br>
   <div class="col-sm-4 badkamers">
    <div class="badkamersText">
     <a href="badkamers.html">
      <h2>
       <span>Badkamers</span>
      </h2>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
      <br>
   <div class="col-sm-4 toiletten">
    <div class="toilettenText">
     <a href="toiletten.html">
      <h2>
       <span>Toiletten</span>
      </h2>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: adding `position:absolute` works. But why does it work?!

Comment: The element hadn't completed its "transition" yet since you had it set to "all". What was happening was the element was transitioning to being visible - at which time it receives it's "positioning". At that point the position is set to "default" which then put it behind the "absolutely" positioned element. You can slow down the transition time to like 5 seconds in your old example and it will stay visible for 5 seconds.

Comment: heehee, you seem to think that I am the OP. Nope. I'm just a bystander.